# What are the different types of instances for KeyFactory?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, private-key

When using `KeyFactory kg = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM)` what are the different algorithms that could be used? I know there is "DSA", "RSA" but which other are supported?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the list of supported algorithms for KeyFactory [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyFactory). You can get a list algorithms supported by other security related classes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html)

- DiffieHellman :  Keys for the Diffie-Hellman KeyAgreement algorithm.
     Note: key.getAlgorithm() will return "DH" instead of
     "DiffieHellman".
- DSA:     Keys for the Digital Signature Algorithm.
- RSA:     Keys for the RSA algorithm (Signature/Cipher).
- EC

Comment: Actually, the correct reference is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html). EC is not supported in any Sun/Oracle provider in Java 6. EC is supported by third-party providers, for example the Bouncycastle provider.